# OpenSearchServer returns blank values NaN

Tags: database, search-engine

By following [these instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061011/how-do-i-access-opensearchserver-database-fields) about autocompletion. I create an Index named suggestions. But when I perform a query it returns blank xml nodes or returns this xml code

```
<response><header><status>0</status><query>expression:php</query></header><result name="response" numFound="108" collapsedDocCount="0" start="0" rows="10" maxScore="NaN" time="1"><doc score="NaN" pos="0">
</doc><doc score="NaN" pos="1">
</doc><doc score="NaN" pos="2">
</doc><doc score="NaN" pos="3">
</doc><doc score="NaN" pos="4">
</doc><doc score="NaN" pos="5">
</doc><doc score="NaN" pos="6">
</doc><doc score="NaN" pos="7">
</doc><doc score="NaN" pos="8">
</doc><doc score="NaN" pos="9">
</doc></result></response>
```

Please help me, How i can retrieve expression field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the query, go to the returned field tab panel, and add the "expression" field.
The NaN score is a normal behavior when the result is sorted by a field (freq).

I also added more details related to the field setup in the initial instructions.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/156a4v6/5 and http://tinypic.com/r/2zipqmc/5 are the snapshots of my work you can see that i have add expression in return fields

Comment: Can you check if the "expression" field has the storage parameter set to "Yes" ? If not, check it, and execute the scheduler again. I added more details in the initial instruction. You may also check them.

Comment: May I request a snapshot of the scheduler job ?

Comment: Thank you! Can you read again the initial instructions, I added some informations related to the scheduler job and the required analyzer for the expression field.

Comment: When i start a scheduler i got this error java.lang.NullPointerExpection

Comment: Can you provide another snapshot of the updated scheduler job ?